# Ensure there is not misspelling in appSettings keys

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing

Let's say we have a web application with a Web.config like this:

```
<configuration>
   <appSettings>
      <add key="ClientCommunicationsBaseUrl" value="http://somehost.dev.com" />
   </appSettings>
<configuration>
```

When the app is deployed, the value ('dev') will be replaced in each environment. This replacement is being done for some of the CD tools out there, for instance, Octopus Deploy.

In any case, the CD tool will expect that the key is written properly. The following will fail.

```
<configuration>
 <appSettings>
    <add key="ClientComunicationsBaseUrl" value="http://somehost.dev.com" />
 </appSettings>
<configuration>
```

Notice there is only one 'm' in ClientComunicationsBaseUrl!!

How could we ensure that all keys in the web.config are correct **before deploy it**?

Comment: Code reviews? The problem can often be, who will check the checker? Possibly a central config repo, that does a config transform in Octopus and adds all the necessary config.

Comment: here, fail means "behave like the key was missing altogether". write a unit test that validates your file (directly, by reading, or indirectly by calling into a suitable entry point of the app). make it part of the release build process.

Comment: Test program, run at build time, that checks the Web.config file?

Comment: Agree with code reviews and also would like to include adding automated tests that can check for such mistakes. There will always be human mistakes like those, but that does not mean you have to let them reach to production. Ensuring that the mistake does not happen is impractical. Ensuring that there is a system in place so that it is discovered what should be done.

Comment: This is the kind of issue that is best handled by a `MissingAppSettingException` or similar after deploying to a test environment. I don't believe it's possible (or practical) to catch everything before deployment. Creating a task to check the config only adds maintenance overhead to the CD process.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to isolate this sort of validation in unit tests. After all, these types of mistakes can happen at any time as developers work on the code, and you want to be alerted any time they occur.

You might want to include an entire suite of tests that check for the following:

1. Are all required settings present?
2. Are all optional settings spelled correctly? (That is, can you retrieve them?)
3. For each setting, is the value one of the acceptable values for the setting?
4. If an optional setting is missing, is there a reasonable default defined and returned for it?

We typically encapsulate all interaction with the configuration in a class (usually named `RuntimeConfig`) that is solely responsible for that work. Unit tests exercise that class. If you abstract that class behind an interface, you can also use mocks to simulate the presence or absence of specific settings and values.